# WIF - Federated Provider MVC application or does it have to be Web Forms?

Tags: wif, single-sign-on

I'm building my own FP STS application.  The Visual Studio STS add in builds an asp.net web forms web site.

Is it possible to make the STS site an MVC application?

We would like to use a bunch of master pages we already have in the MVC world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Identity Server](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/). It's an MVC 3 STS.